# How to specify the font of markdown tables (or optionally using pandoc)?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I would like to display tables in the crisp format of `pandas`: very small but clear fonts.  The default `markdown` uses the same font as the surrounding text - which is far too large.

Either a document-level or a table-by-table directive and either native *markdown* or *pandoc* would be fine/helpful to use.

The output is `pdf` : here is the command presently being used:

```
pandoc --toc -V fontsize=9pt --pdf-engine xelatex 
-V geometry:"left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm" -o Task1.pdf Task1.md
```

Comment: you don't say what you're converting to.... html or pdf via latex, or..?

Comment: I did not realize that that mattered: this pandoc/latex is complicated. The command line I'm using was in any case added

Comment: then you can inject some LaTeX using `--include-in-header` or in the metadata of the markdown file, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserting `tex` directives actually helps here

```
\tiny
cola|colb|colc
---|---|---
a|b|c
\normalsize
```

I wonder if there were a way to specify what `\tiny` resolves to - since I'd like it even smaller.